# Play store does not push new versions on "Internal Testing" to users

Tags: google-play, google-play-console

I have an app on the "Internal Testing" track with a couple of friends as registered testers. They could all install it, no issues here. But they don't get updates automatically when I publish a new version on this track. The only way to install new updates is to uninstall the app and install it again via the invite link.

First thing I learned about this is that Google will not enable auto updates on Internal Testing if they haven't done at least one review of the app (although the track itself doesn't get reviewed). So you have to submit one version on the "Closed Testing" track in order to get it reviewed. I did this and it got accepted but still no updates on "Internal Testing".

Since I got reviewed on "Closed Testing" I published several new versions on "Internal Testing" but none got pushed to my users. They don't even see the update if they actively search for updates in the Play Store app.

I didn't find much explicit information about what to expect from the "Internal Testing" track wrt. updates, but this post says that it should be deployed automatically if the user has set their device to auto-update apps:

> If your users have their device set to auto update apps, it will just update to the newest release when the device recognizes a release is available. ([source](https://forum.adalo.com/t/android-internal-test-im-struggling-to-get-my-testers-to-download-and-updating-their-installed-app/13999/2))

What am I doing wrong here?

If this is not possible with "Internal Testing": what would be the right method to give a limited number of test user access to the app *with auto-updates* enabled?

Thanks in advance!

Edit: I found one way to update the app: if I long-tap the App icon and tap the (i) icon (this might be Samsung specific), I end up in the Play Store listing which shows an update button. The auto-updates are enabled btw, so it should have been installed automatically.

Comment: Having similar issues here. Internal tracks seem to be fragile and/or broken. Not to mention that they don't even tell you that you have to release to alpha and get reviewed before the internal track will even work in the first place.

Comment: Yeah, Google Play Store is still a mess for developers (although it was way worse some years ago...)

Answer (score 4):

What I found is that testers list should be exclusive for different testing tracks. In other words, a tester should not have the same Android device trying to access internal testing track releases and open / closed testing track releases.

Did not find any official documentation from PlayStore on this, but learnt it the hard way.
Maybe this post is still helpful for you: https://medium.com/@tukai.anirban/internal-testing-in-google-playstore-47de955062ad